# Empty uploaded file in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, upload

I want to upload a csv file with a form but if the file is too big (> 200 rows) it doesn't work.

For instance, when I upload a big file and I do:

```
 die(var_dump($request->files->get('file')));
```

Here is the result:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false)
["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(12) "big_file.csv" 
["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" 
["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) 
["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(1) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(0) "" 
["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(0) "" }
```

As you can see, the size is 0, the fileName and the pathName are empty and the mime type is wrong (it should be text/csv).
And when I upload a small file (around 100 rows) it works, there is the good size, the pathName/fileName etc.

Do you know if it's a problem with PHP?

FYI, I have these settings in the PHP code:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 600);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
set_time_limit(0);
```

Regards

Comment: Are you using the builtin webserver or apache/nginx/... ? There are default restrictions to the maximum request body size (which includes the uploaded files) in place with any modern webserver which can be raised/configured. This is likely the cause for your problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm using Apache2. I try to set the LimitRequestBody param to 50 MB in the .htaccess or in the virtual host but it still doesn't work. Moreover, the default value of this param is normally 0 (illimited request body size) when it's not set.

Comment: Hm okay ... what's the output of `$request->files->get('file')->getError()` and `$request->files->get('file')->getErrorMessage()` and `UploadedFile::getMaxSize()`?

Comment: The error is: "The file "big_file.csv" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)."
It’s odd because I set: ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');
So I changed the value of upload_max_filesize (and the value of post_max_size because it is ignored too) in the php.ini file and now it works. Thank you very much.
Do you know why my ini_set() calls are ignored?

Answer (score 1):

The file fails to upload because its size is bigger than permitted in PHP configuration files.

You can see that by looking at the error that is generated from this method:

```
$request->files->get('file')->getErrorMessage()
```

You can achieve this with a few easy steps.

**Override php.ini directly:**

Edit your `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` (instead of 7.4 use your version - how to find your version is explained when you read further, in short write in terminal `php -v` and use 2 digits e.g. 7.4)

Find there "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" then change the values to (use what ever size you need, I used 20 Megabytes e.g. 20M):

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M 
post_max_size = 20M
```

Then Save the file and restart Apache in my case the command is:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Or you might need to use sudo before:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Or in other cases:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Should work now.

**Another option is to override php.ini without changing the file directly:**

Echo or Print or Return the following function `phpinfo()` from your code from the response you will find a column with the name "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" I got there the following path: `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d`

If you have trouble to get response from `phpinfo()`, just write in terminal `php -v` this will give you the version of your PHP so if you will see there:

```
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
```

Use only the first 2 digits of the version and go to this folder I mentioned  `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d` (Instead of 7.4 type your 2 digit version)

In your conf.d directory create a file named: `file-upload.ini` (you can call the file as you like as long as it finishes with .ini).
This directory files overrides your php.ini settings

So create the file and write inside (use inside what ever file size you need, I used 20M):

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M 
post_max_size = 20M
```

Then Save the file then restart Apache with the commands I mentioned above.

Now the file should be uploaded successfully.